# Does crew headcount or race influence oxygen usage?

Tags: ftl-faster-than-light

My ship has a fixed volume, but my crew count can range from 1 to 8 and include various species. Do either of those two factors influence the rate of oxygen consumption?

Answer (score 69, accepted):

**TL;DR.** --> No. The rate is fixed.

**For Science!** --> I ran a series of tests, each iteration tracking the amount of time necessary to go from 100% oxygen to 25% oxygen with all internal doors open. I stopped here to avoid damaging my crew's health and thereby requiring time in sickbay before the next iteration began.

Results were as follows:

```
SHIP       CREW      75% O2 USE     NOTES
Kestrel    3H          63s
Kestrel    2H          63s          RIP Mr Buga
Kestrel    1H          63s          RIP Nikmi
Red-Tail   2H1Z1M      63s
Red-Tail   1Z1M        63s          RIP Hassifa & Beth
Red-Tail   1M          63s          RIP Luaan Ti
```

As you can see, from one crew to four the oxygen depletion rate remains constant. The rate is also not affected by Mantis or Zoltan biological distinctiveness.

Thus, one must recommend the immediate cessation of emergency crew execution measures intending to reduce oxygen depletion as this approach is demonstrably ineffective.

Comment: Some members of some races were hurt in the making of this answer.

Comment: If you turn of O2 and have all doors shut, oxygen will only deplete from rooms with people in, correct? Can you get more O2 time by leaving people in rooms until they go red, and then moving them to a new room? Based on your results does crewmembers / room not make any difference in this case too?

Comment: No, the O2 usage by crew is flat across rooms. Only accelerated loss - such as breaches or open doors - creates room-by-room differences.

Comment: Slight change with FTL Advanced Edition - Lanius drain air from the room they're in quite quickly.

Comment: @Brilliand - I can feel some tests coming on...